# how to change gridview size

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Hey guys I am having trouble changing the length and width of the gridview. It is bound and every time I change the size  in the designer or in the code it keeps resetting. What is the problem?

Comment: It has Dock property set? What happends if you set a size programmatically?

Comment: thanks for answering but nothing at all

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to change the size to something greater than the maximum or less than the minimum?

Answer (score 0):

For custom client-side sizing, you'll want to create a CSS class with the sizes that you want assigned to the table.

All you have to do is examine the html generated by the framework on the client side and then write CSS rules for it.

For example, a vanilla gridview without any styling generates the following HTML:

```
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="MainContent_GridView1" 
   style="border-collapse:collapse;">
```

So in your CSS, you can write:

```
#MainContent-GridView{
   height: your_height_px;
   width : your_width_px;
}
```

You can do the same by assigning a css class to it, if you want. (that's the route I'd go, so that I can apply the css to as many gridviews/tables as needed...)

Comment: Hey Guys I done it. Newbie mistake. I wrapped the gridview into a div but didn't know I had to move gridview into the div so I could see it when debugging.